# rails won't save form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, save

I have a formfield in my form like this:

```
<div class="tags">
  <%= f.label :tags %>
  <%= f.text_area :tags %>
</div>
```

I ran a migration like this:

```
class AddTagsToIssues < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :issues, :tags, :text
  end
end
```

When i save, the new row is added to db, but tags = nil, although I typed something like 'test' in de text_area

in my development log I have:

Unpermitted parameters: tags

I have tried whitelisting in my controller:

```
 def create
    @issue = Issue.new(issue_params)
    Issue.new(params.permit(:tags))
```

but this doesn't work.

Update for follow up question:

Full create method:

```
def create
    def issue_params    
    params.require(:issue).permit(:tags) 
    end
    @issue = Issue.new(issue_params)
    Issue.new(params.permit(:tags))
    respond_to do |format|
      if @issue.save
        format.html { redirect_to @issue, notice: 'Issue was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @issue }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @issue.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The model:

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :project

end
```

The table create query:

```
class CreateIssues < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :issues do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.integer :no_followers

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

So with this I don't have permission problems, that only happened with the later adding of the tags, and then only with the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tags` is being set as `nil` because you have not permitted it.

Permit `tags` in the `issue_params` method as below:

```
 def issue_params    
    params.require(:issue).permit(:tags,...) 
 end
```

where, `...` refers to other fields in model `Issue`.

Your `create` action should look something like this,

```
 def create
    @issue = Issue.new(issue_params)   ## issue_params called 
    if @issue.save                     ## save the record
      redirect_to @issue, notice: 'Issue was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks! Follow up question: why do I have to do this for this new param while the rest is being saved anyway?

Comment: The rest is being saved because you have permitted the rest of params. If you don't permit `tags` it will never be saved.

Comment: But how did I permit the other params? My code is now updated with: params.require(:issue).permit(:tags). Notice that I didn't permit the other params here. Still they are saved like the tags, and were saved before I had the migration: add_column :issues, :tags, :text

Comment: You might have permitted them explicitly while creating the instance, not by calling issue_params. Share the code for saving the record, I can explain better then.

Comment: Do you still have the issue?

Comment: You have solved the bug so thats great. Im just still confused about why i don't have to 'whitelist' the other params, and they're still saved properly to the database. I've update my question with more code.

Comment: Then please accept the answer. So, I get rewarded for my hard work.:)